PhpMyAdmin5.2.1 cache problem when running php script
I have wampserver3.3.7, PhpMyadmin5.2.1, PHP8.2.2 and MySql9.1.
When I open PhpMyadmin into my Firefox browser and run a php script that will update and replace a large 500MB mysql table, this update can take 1 hour and during this time, I reload (refresh) my PhpMyadmin page to see if everything is going well because there are different steps in my update that allow me to see the number of entries in my table so that I know if everything is going well.
PhpMyAdmin: table view
PhpMyAdmin: all tables
But when I refresh my different tables into my PhpMyadmin page, it indicates me the number of entries of my old table, as if there was some kind of cache that does not take into account the update of my php script that is running. Do you know how to fix this so that PhpMyadmin tells me the number of entries in my table based on the progress of the update of my php script?
Thanks in advance for your help.

My guess is that phpmyadmin gets the row counts from mysql metadata views, which contain estimates and are not refreshed every time you insert data into a table. If this is the case, an analyse table statement can force mysql to update these row counts.

Thank you Shadow for your aswer, it work fine when I make into my php script an analyse mysql table statement.
